# Popup UserCreationForm in Django

Tags: javascript, python, django, twitter-bootstrap

Can I popup `UserCreationForm` of Django?

I am building a website. When I click on signup page popup signup page needs to show.

Right now I have a signup page and login page and they are working but I need to popup them.

I am using `usercreationform` of Django.

Can I add Bootstrap and CSS in that form too?

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
```

Here is the popup code of what i tried
right now the div is showing on my page not in popup

Sign-up

```
<script src='{% static "js/grayscale.min.js" %}'></script>
      <script src='{% static "js/creative.min.js"%}'></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
  var model= document.getElementById('abc');
  window.onclick= function(event){
    if (event.target==model) {
      model.style.display= "none";
    }
  }
      </script>  

<div id="abc">

    <div id="popupContact">
    {% block title %}

{% endblock %}
    {% block content %}

       <div class="login" style="background: grey">

         {% if messages %}
            <ul>
                {% for message in messages %}
                <li>{{ message }}</li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        {% endif %}

        <h1>Create account - Racernomics</h1>

         <form method="post" >
             {% csrf_token %}
             <table>
                {{ form.as_table }}
                 <tr>
                    <td></td>
                     <td><button type="submit">Register</button></td>
                </tr>
             </table>
         </form>
       {% endblock %}
</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Django forms give you the html code to display a form - you can wrap this html into a container (the popup) that's displayed by javascript on click. This is the general approach I would take, I can't really be more specific since your question is pretty vague. What have you tried so far?

Comment: sir right now what you have suggest i'm exactly thinking the same thing. but i wasn't sure about the urls do i need to set them too or just put the html code in a div and then just use javasript?

Comment: @Dunno sir i have tried what you said used javascript and wrap it into an html but it didn't worked. i have edited my Post check that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can customize your form however you want.

It could be done by adding html-classes, id`s, etc. directly to your form class in django and then accessing and modifying them with css:

```
class SomeForm(forms.Form):
    some_field = forms.DateField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'datepicker', 'placeholder': 'mm/dd/yy'}),
                           required=False)
```

or you can use for example additional library to access form in template (I prefer this way, it helps to keep logic and frontend separate from each other). Such library could be ***widget-tweaks***.

Take a look at this [article](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/article/2017/08/19/how-to-render-django-form-manually.html), could be interesting for you.

Comment: thanks mate. i need a bit more help here my sessions are not destrying can you help me with that? i mean when i logout the user it redirects me to the logout page but when i click on the back button its takes my back to my dashboard page. \

Comment: @DawoodBasharat do u have a check for authenticated user at your view of dashboard?

Comment: @micheal sir i also need help in showing popup. I have edited my post

Comment: you mean about this check? def login(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        return redirect('Dashboard')

Comment: @DawoodBasharat try using `login_required` decoraor instead. Only thing you need with that, it to decorate your view. Take a look at documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator

Comment: @DawoodBasharat and add `LOGIN_URL` variable into your settings to specify your redirecting view

Comment: talking about js, what actually doesn't work? popup isn't showed up?

Comment: @DawoodBasharat that could be issue with js then, not with django. Open browser diagnosis and check which error it shows. Instruction: https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Your_Browser_to_Diagnose_JavaScript_Errors (STEP 3)

Comment: but sir the same code i tried in another html page and it worked there. let me check it again

Comment: @DawoodBasharat maybe I don't understand you correctly, can you see at least submit button at popup, or popup isn't showed at all? if nothing even shows up, that is an issue with js